# How to update an object's properties dynamically with Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

In the attached [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ssundheim/ar6dY/), I'm trying to create a page that compares the stats of two airplanes, where the user can choose each plane from a select menu.

I use a constructor to build the stats for each plane via an ID number, and the "specs" (properties) are pulled in from an array of non-editable data. This works upon page load, but when I change the value of an ID, eg "myPlaneId", the object "MyPlaneSpecs"  doesn't update.

Should I be approaching this differently? This is my first Knockout project so I know I'm probably missing something obvious.

See [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ssundheim/ar6dY/).

In that example, you can see the planeId's are updating, but the overall plane specs are not.

```
<h1>Plane Comparison</h1>
  Your plane: <select data-bind="options: planes, optionsValue: 'id', value: myPlaneId,  optionsText: 'name'"></select>
  <br>
  Their plane: <select data-bind="options: planes, optionsValue: 'id', value: theirPlaneId, optionsText: 'name'"></select>

  <h2>Your plane specs: </h2>
  ID: <span data-bind="text: myPlaneId"></span> <br>
  Name: <span data-bind="text: myPlaneSpecs().planeName"></span> <br>
  Max Speed:    <span data-bind="text: myPlaneSpecs().speed"></span> <br>
  Climb Rate:    <span data-bind="text: myPlaneSpecs().climbrate"></span>
  <br><br>
  <h2>Their plane specs: </h2>
  ID: <span data-bind="text: theirPlaneId"></span> <br>
  Name: <span data-bind="text: theirPlaneSpecs().planeName"></span> <br>
  Max Speed:    <span data-bind="text: theirPlaneSpecs().speed"></span> <br>
  Climb Rate:    <span data-bind="text: theirPlaneSpecs().climbrate"></span>


       <script>

    // Class to represent a chosen plane
    function PlaneSpecs(specsArray) {
      this.specs = ko.observable(specsArray);
      this.planeId = this.specs().id;
      this.planeName = this.specs().name;
      this.speed = this.specs().speed;
      this.climbrate = this.specs().climbrate;
    }

    // Overall viewmodel for this screen
    function DogfightViewModel() {
      var self = this;
      self.myPlaneId = ko.observable(0);
      self.theirPlaneId =  ko.observable(1);

      // Non-editable catalog data
      self.planes = [
        { id: 0, name: "P-47D Thunderbolt", speed: 690, climbrate: 16, turntime: 25.8 },
        { id: 1, name: "BF 109 F4", speed: 660, climbrate: 18, turntime: 20.2 },
        { id: 2, name: "F6F-3 Hellcat", speed: 639, climbrate: 22.8, turntime: 21.8 }
      ];

      myPlaneSpecs = ko.observable(
         new PlaneSpecs(self.planes[self.myPlaneId()])   //This doesn't get updated when the ID changes
      );
      theirPlaneSpecs = ko.observable(
        new PlaneSpecs(self.planes[self.theirPlaneId()])
      );

    }

    ko.applyBindings(new DogfightViewModel());

  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `ko.computed` to achieve that which you want. If you would create a function to get the plane by id, like to the following (my version below does not have any error handling or check to ensure that the plane actually exists):

```
function getPlaneById(id){
    var selectedPlane = self.planes.filter(function(plane){ return plane.id === id })[0];
    return new PlaneSpecs(selectedPlane);
}
```

You could then change your myPlaneSpecs and theirPlaneSpecs to be computed like so:

```
self.myPlaneSpecs = ko.computed(function(){
    return getPlaneById(self.myPlaneId());
});
self.theirPlaneSpecs = ko.computed(function(){
    return getPlaneById(self.theirPlaneId());
});
```

Further, you don't really use the observable you create in the PlaneSpecs constructor, so I suggest removing that and instead doing something like:

```
function PlaneSpecs(specs) {
    this.planeId = specs.id;
    this.planeName = specs.name;
    this.speed = specs.speed;
    this.climbrate = specs.climbrate;
}
```

You could also simplify your plane information bindings using the `with` binding, like the following (which could be done both for `myPlaneSpecs` and `theirPlaneSpecs`):

```
<div data-bind="with:myPlaneSpecs">
    <h2>Your plane specs: </h2>
    ID: <span data-bind="text: planeId"></span> <br>
    Name: <span data-bind="text: planeName"></span> <br> 
    Max Speed:    <span data-bind="text: speed"></span> <br>
    Climb Rate:    <span data-bind="text: climbrate"></span>
</div>
```

*Edit: Adding usage of knockout templates*.

Since you're displaying both plane specs in the same way you could also create a template for the plane spec display, like the following:

```
<script type="text/html" id="planeTemplate">    
    ID: <span data-bind="text: planeId"></span> <br>
    Name: <span data-bind="text: planeName"></span> <br>    
    Max Speed:    <span data-bind="text: speed"></span> <br>
    Climb Rate:    <span data-bind="text: climbrate"></span>
</script>
```

After which you could display the plane specs for both `myPlaneSpecs` and `theirPlaneSpecs` using that template, with the following markup:

```
<h2>Your plane specs: </h2>
<div data-bind="template:{ name: 'planeTemplate', data: myPlaneSpecs}"></div>

<h2>Their plane specs: </h2>
<div data-bind="template:{ name: 'planeTemplate', data: theirPlaneSpecs}"></div>
```

_Edit: Adding link to updated jsfiddle

I have updated your fiddle with the above code, including template usage, which you can find at http://jsfiddle.net/ar6dY/6/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and you helped me learn some important things. Thanks!

Comment: You can get rid of both myPlaneSpecs and theirPlaneSpecs computedObservables by removing the optionsValue binding and binding value directly.  Knockout is doing a lot more work than it really needs to.

Comment: Indeed, that's a good suggestion. We would then also have to remember to change the `planes` array to be an array of viewmodels objects (objects created with the `PlaneSpecs` constructor) instead of an array of DTOs (which is seems like it is currently), otherwise the selected object would not not be `PlaneSpecs`. This might, of course, be preferable to do in either case. It could, though, be less than preferable, if we would also change the selected `myPlaneSpecs` object and not want to make those changes also appear on the `theirPlaneSpecs` object.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of quirks with the options binding set( "options", "optionsValue", "optionsText" and "value").

If you use optionsValue binding then the "value" binding's observable ( myPlaneId ) will be set with the value of each option ( in your case the value of the "id" property ).

When MyPlaneId value changes you don't have anything will recalculate the properties on myPlaneSpecs observable.  An observable will NOT change in response to any other observable's changing.  That is what a computed observable is for.

If you don't supply an optionsValue binding, then the whole object literal will be stored in the backing observable.

With this in mind you can vastly simplify this example

1. Stop using optionsValue and store the entire selected element's object literal.
2. Rename self.myPlaneId to self.myPlane and adjust value binding
3. Rename self.theirPlaneId to self.theirPlane and adjust value binding
4. You don't need a PlaneSpecs class, just bind directly to the object literal.  Use a "with" virtual binding to make the HTML a little easier to read ( and notice the potential reuse of the html between myPlane and theirPlane.
5. (optional) Convert self.planes to an observableArray.  It will make it easier in the future if the array source is dynamically set ( like from an AJAX response ).

If you don't like using the with virtual binding, then change the HTML below to added either myPlane() or theirPlane() to each respective span.

ie

```
<span data-bind="text: id"></span>
```

to

```
<span data-bind="text: myPlane().id"></span>
```

---

```
<h1>Plane Comparison</h1>
  Your plane:
  <select data-bind="options: planes, value: myPlane,  optionsText: 'name'"></select>
  <br>
  Their plane: <select data-bind="options: planes, value: theirPlane, optionsText: 'name'"></select>

  <h2>Your plane specs: </h2>
  <!-- ko with: myPlane -->
  ID: <span data-bind="text: id"></span> <br>
  Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <br>
  Max Speed:    <span data-bind="text: speed"></span> <br>
  Climb Rate:    <span data-bind="text: climbrate"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <br><br>
  <h2>Their plane specs: </h2>

  <!-- ko with: theirPlane -->
  ID: <span data-bind="text: id"></span> <br>
  Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span> <br>
  Max Speed:    <span data-bind="text: speed"></span> <br>
  Climb Rate:    <span data-bind="text: climbrate"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
```

---

```
    // Overall viewmodel for this screen
    function DogfightViewModel() {
      var self = this;

      // Non-editable catalog data
      self.planes = ko.observableArray( [
        { id: 0, name: "P-47D Thunderbolt", speed: 690, climbrate: 16, turntime: 25.8 },
        { id: 1, name: "BF 109 F4", speed: 660, climbrate: 18, turntime: 20.2 },
        { id: 2, name: "F6F-3 Hellcat", speed: 639, climbrate: 22.8, turntime: 21.8 }
      ] );

      self.myPlane = ko.observable(self.planes()[0]);
      self.theirPlane =  ko.observable(self.planes()[1]);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new DogfightViewModel());
```